# Cross-posting to unix.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, stackexchange, communities

If I have a question that is Unix sysadmin related. It's not clear to me whether it should go to serverfault or unix.stackexchange.com. Is cross-posting acceptable? The specific question I have in mind is [183337](https://serverfault.com/questions/183337/connect-to-kvm-instance-using-virsh-when-image-launched-through-eucalyptus).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since unix is beta at the moment, and we can't move questions there until it isn't, I believe cross-posting is permitted.

Comment: Is unix.stackexchange.com still a beta?.. But the migration option is not there.

Comment: Mods can now migrate to Unix.SE, as well as other Beta sites. So this no longer applies (it was correct at the time). Please do not cross-post.

Answer (score 2):

Your question prompted me to ask this:
[Could Appropriate Tags Cross-Post to Relevant SE Communities?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/840/could-appropriate-tags-cross-post-to-relevant-se-communities)