# Could Appropriate Tags Cross-Post to Relevant SE Communities?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stackexchange, communities

Since the recent addition of new communities for Unix and Ubuntu within the StackExchange (particularly ServerFault), I propose that tags posted to SF with relevant tags ("Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Unix", etc.) be automatically cross-posted (or linked) to those communities.

I think that this would allow those who wish to focus on their chosen area of interest to only look in those communities , but maximize coverage for Question Askers ("Questioners"?   "Queryphiles"?  "Inquisitors"?), such that they would only need to post to SF, but those relevant tagged questions would filter down to the sub-communities.

(And answer q[uestions such as this](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/838/cross-posting-to-unix-stackexchange-com).)

Answer (score 2):

I really like that idea. Don't know how much coding it would take but it would certainly be a great enhancement to the overall site.

I'm primarily a Windows admin, so tend to focus mostly on Windows questions. I also have a few Linux machines for special jobs (firewall, spam filter, etc.), so still have some interest in that area. As I am unlikely to ever be a regular on a dedicated *nix site having suitably tagged questions also appear on SF would be great for someone like myself, who would otherwise miss out on quite a lot of what is currently posted on SF but is likely in future to be only posted on the more specialised site.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I don't know enough about the SE codebase to comment on the ease, but I assume that such an effort would be significant...

Answer (score 2):

Cross posting maybe problematic, but it might be nice if clicking on a tag brought up all the questions with the same tag across all the Stack Exchange sites.  Would that be possible using some of the same code used for the StackExchange menu at the top?

Having some kind of indicator of which tags were in use in multiple locations might also be handy.  Although it would be very bad to lose the ability to keep info on different sites separate - if questions on email on superuser.com bled onto serverfault.com that would be a bad thing...